# Is there any API available to deploy an application on mule management console(MMC) cluster

Tags: mule, mule-module-jpa

I am trying to write scripts(using java) to deploy my mule application on top of the cluster. So that, application get deployed on the Mule ESB servers under cluster.

Already I have written a code to deploy my mule application on Mule ESB server using MMC Rest API(http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MMC+REST+API)

Now my next target is to deploy application on MMC cluster.

Can any one please suggest me a way to deploy mule application on cluster from java code(using API).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "MMC cluster"?

Comment: In Mule Management Console, we can add multiple Mule ESB server then we would be able create a cluster with added ESB servers. I want to deploy my mule application on cluster in Mule Management console using java code.

Comment: Do we have any CLUSTER REST API to do deployment like how we have for REST API for MMC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MMC REST API allows to deploy to a cluster the same way as you deploy to a standalone server:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deployments

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Java code ... why don't you try Maven ... Maven Script directly create application zip and deploy to mmc cluster ... All you need to write the script in **.pom** file instead of java class

Comment: Could you please direct me to any documentation of such maven script. Would I be able to monitor the application on MMC?

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plug in that you can use to deploy via MMC:

https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/Maven-Mule-REST-Plugin

```
mule-mmc-rest-plugin:deploy
```

This will:

- delete an existing mule application archive from the MMC Repository if version contains "SNAPSHOT"
- upload the mule application archive to the MMC Repository
- delete an existing deployment having the same application name
- create a new deployment this the uploaded archive, with target the
  given serverGroup
- perform a deploy request to make MMC deploy into target server group

I used it and it works (but you may need to make it some customizations)